# Let A a subset of X be a finite dimensional linear subspace. Show that A is complete

Tags: normed-spaces

Let X be a normed space. Let A a subset of X be a finite dimensional linear subspace. Show that A is complete (even if X is not).

Using the above show that A is a closed subset of X.

For the first part do I need to generalise it to $\mathbb{R^n}$ or is there a quicker way?

I think I can do the second bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a basis for $A$, the components in that basis give a vector $x(y)$ of $\mathbb R^n$ for each $y\in A$, where $n$ is the dimension of $A$. Note that a sequence $y_n$ in $A$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $x_n=x(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^n$. From now on you can thus proceed as if $A$ was $\mathbb R^n$. This implies that $A$ is complete (because $\mathbb R^n$ is complete, with respect to any norm, since all norms are equivalent) and so it is also closed (since any convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence and so has a limit in the space).

*Added:*

On the claim "a sequence $y_n$ in $A$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $x_n=x(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^n$". Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis of $A$, say with $\|v_i\|=1$ for each $i$. Given a vector $v\in A$ one can write $v=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n$ in a unique manner. This gives the bijection $v\mapsto (c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ from $A$ onto $\mathbb R^n$.

Now let $w_k$ be a sequence in $A$ and write $w_k=c_1(k)v_1+\cdots+c_n(k)v_n$. Note that
$$
\|w_k-w_l\|\le \sum_{i=1}^n|c_i(k)-c_i(l)|
$$
and so if $(c_1(k),\ldots,c_n(k))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^n$, then $w_k$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$. Let me leave as an exercise showing that the converse also holds (hint: all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent).

Comment: Could you make it more formal please. I do not understand what you mean by components in that basis..

Comment: Components of $v$ in a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ are the numbers $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ such that $v=c_1e_1+\cdots+c_ne_n$, right?

Comment: So I don't have to prove anything just state the basis and the theorems?

Comment: If you understand my answer, you can detail it as much as you may need. It really depends for what you want it,as I wrote it is fine for a book, perhaps not if it is homework... Of course, it is always more difficult to write mathematics in a short manner while still complete, but often not much appreciated in homework...

Comment: Ok so I have a basis with dimension n. The components (the scalars) form a vector x(v) of R^n for each v in A. Now I have to show cauchy convergence? Or is that iff to show A can be assumed to be R^n?

Comment: Your choice, depending on what it is for. But note that $x(v_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only the components, say $(c_1(v_k),\ldots,c_n(v_k))$, form a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^n$. Depending on what it is for, you may also want to prove this statement!

Comment: I have not actually come across that theorem , is there any other way?

Comment: Not a theorem, much simpler. I will a few details to my answer.

Comment: What is the vk inside the components and the k?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but you really need to make an effort. Especially if this is homework.

Comment: I'm confused about your notation. In your comments you said c1(vk) but in the answer you said c1(k)?

Comment: I see. I changed the notation in the answer, because it was convenient due to the rest of the notation. It is better to look only at the answer.

Comment: Why is it closed. I only have a lemma for banach spaces (but x does not have to be complete here).